# Would you fix this vbs to execute this bat file with admin priviledge

Tags: vbscript

Under windows 7 with uac activated.

This is all around an issue. THIS ISSUE:

[upnphost excessive cpu load](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/fr-FR/65b99493-800b-4d6c-b05b-d3bb39ed4083/excessive-cpu-on-svchost-due-to-upnphost?forum=w7itproperf)

Especifically:

> Mine has this problem frequently, and I hate to go restart the upnphost service all the time, so instead i just created a task in the
>   task scheduler to run a once a day, and repeat every 5 minutes. The
>   task runs a .bat file:
>
> net stop upnphost 
>   net start upnphost
>
> if you want to make it run in the background without the cmd window
>   coming up, run this .vbs with the above .bat already created as
>   "C:\upnphost.bat":
>
> Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
>   WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\upnphost.bat" & Chr(34), 0 Set 
>   WshShell = Nothing
>
> this way the upnphost service will automatically restart every 5
>   minutes with no visible presentation, so if it decides to misbehave
>   and go high cpu, it will be for 5 minutes tops, you could change this
>   to any interval you want.

Everything works except for the fact that for the bat to actually work i need to right click directly on the bat and execute as admin.

For that reason if i click the vbs it will execute it but not as admin and it wont work.

So scheduling it as a task wont work either.

Can you fix the code in the vbs:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
 WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\upnphost.bat" & Chr(34), 0 Set 
 WshShell = Nothing
```

So it executes the bat with admin priviledge.
It that matters, my route to the bat has spaces.

Respectfully

Answer (score 0):

You can launch an program as an administrator with UAC enabled, but you'll still get prompted whether you want to launch this program. For example,

```
Set objSA = CreateObject ("Shell.Application")
objSA.ShellExecute "cmd.exe","uac","","runas",1
```

However,

I was able to use this vbscript to stop and restart this service using a scheduled task, setting the task to run as "Hidden" and run with the highest privileges.

```
strService = "upnphost"
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colService = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT Name FROM Win32_Service " _
& "where Name='" & strService & "'")

For Each objService In colService
    return = objService.StopService()
    return = objService.StartService()
Next
```

Comment: Nothing happens, if i manually execute the vbs service keeps running according to resmon. If i use the bat it restarts and you can see it in service stop run column.

Answer (score 0):

The scheduled task must be run as a user who can start and stop the service (usually an admin account) and with the option "Run with highest privileges" enabled.

[image]